# Azure functions - Read all files from SFTP location

Tags: c#, .net, azure, sftp, azure-functions

I need to read all the text files available from a SFTP location(without specifying filename) using Azure function triggers.
Currently, I am able to read a particular file when the name of the file is specfied - as below:
**ExternalFileTrigger**
**Binding:**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "apiHubFileTrigger",
      "name": "input",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "Outbox",
      "connection": "sftp1_SFTP"
    },
    {
      "type": "apiHubFile",
      "name": "output",
      "direction": "out",
      "path": "Inbox/test.txt",
      "connection": "googledrive_GOOGLEDRIVE"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

**Func:**

```
using System;
public static void Run(string input, out string output, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("File found: "+input);
    output = input;
}
```

**Request Body:**

```
Outbox/test.txt
```

Note: Any file irrespective of filename pushed to SFTP location should be read by the Azure function.

Comment: You've not made much of an attempt here, I don't see any sftp code. Have a look into https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET you can use it to connect to your sftp server and retrieve the filenames.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your comments. I did use SSH.NET to connect SFTP. But i was looking to do the same thing using input/output bindings. Also i want to delete the file from SFTP location once it is read.

Comment: Your trigger does not specify the file name. What am I missing?

Comment: The binding should not contain the file name and pull all the text files from the specified folder

Comment: @pmcilreavy Azure functions don't have SFTP code when connecting to an SFTP site. You build the connection in the tool.

Comment: @rahul where you able to get this to work? I have had problems using the SFTP connector with Azure Functions and Logic Apps to monitor a folder for new or modified files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Binding parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#Trigger%20metadata%20properties) instead of hard coding file Name: test.txt. You can also specify patterns for the filename. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#Binding%20expressions%20and%20patterns) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

But why go to the trouble of instantiating the SFTP client yourself?

Just use the prebuilt [SFTP connector in Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sftp), and call the Function to further do your custom processing. You can probably do everything inside the Logic App if your goal is to [store the file in Google Drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-googledrive).

[image: SFTP connector screencap]

Comment: The Azure Function uses the same SFTP connector that is available in Logic Apps.